# Input data is not a complete block?

Tags: c#, pdf, cryptography

I am trying to make a batch PDF unlocker for PDFs that are labeled secured. I can open these files without a password, but I can't modify it. My test PDF can be unlocked using online tools so I thought if doing it programmatic in C# was possible. Below is my sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    string inputfile = @"V:\rwong\Work Files\Secured PDF\Test_15.PDF";
    string outputfile = @"V:\rwong\Work Files\Secured PDF\Test_15_Unsecured.PDF";
    Decrypt(inputfile, outputfile);
}

private static void Decrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    int data;
                    while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                    {
                        fsOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. I keep getting an error on `while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)`
   but I do not know how to fix it. It says the `input data is not a complete block`
2. Is it even possible to do what I am trying to achieve, wasting my time or am I going the wrong way with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the file *actually* just a file entirely encrypted with that key? It seems unlikely. I suspect PDF has an "encrypted file container" aspect to it - it's not just a matter of decrypting it as a stream of data.

Comment: Based on your comment, it sounds like I need a different key for each file. I can't brute force it?

Comment: Well I'd expect there to be a different key for each file - but it's more that you're assuming it's just a file which is entirely encrypted, whereas I expect the encryption to be part of the PDF container... basically, this isn't how I expect you to decrypt an encrypted PDF file.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarity.  I'm guessing unlocking generic PDFs will take a lot more than the code I wrote above.

Comment: If you do research you will find that there are already libraries out there. If everybody doesn't do any research before programming then the PDF creator may not have bothered to do any encryption in the first place. Just trying things at random will take forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is not by any means a full solution to your problem.  However, assuming this method of applying encryption is still in use including for whole-document PDF encryption, it might give you some insight into how you'd need to construct your own bulk decryption program if you are still inclined to do so.  This is an excerpt from an Adobe document dated 2008:

Algorithm 1: Encryption of data using the RC4 or AES algorithms

a) Obtain the object number and generation number from the object identifier of the string or stream to be encrypted (see 7.3.10, "Indirect Objects"). If the string is a direct object, use the identifier of the indirect object containing it.

b) For all strings and streams without crypt filter specifier; treating the object number and generation number as binary integers, extend the original n-byte encryption key to n + 5 bytes by appending the low-order 3 bytes of the object number and the low-order 2 bytes of the generation number in that order, low-order byte first. (n is 5 unless the value of V in the encryption dictionary is greater than 1, in which case n is the value of Length divided by 8.)  If using the AES algorithm, extend the encryption key an additional 4 bytes by adding the value “sAlT”, which corresponds to the hexadecimal values 0x73, 0x41, 0x6C, 0x54. (This addition is done for backward compatibility and is not intended to provide additional security.)

c) Initialize the MD5 hash function and pass the result of step (b) as input to this function.

d) Use the first (n + 5) bytes, up to a maximum of 16, of the output from the MD5 hash as the key for the RC4 or AES symmetric key algorithms, along with the string or stream data to be encrypted.  If using the AES algorithm, the Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode, which requires an initialization vector, is used. The block size parameter is set to 16 bytes, and the initialization vector is a 16-byte random number that is stored as the first 16 bytes of the encrypted stream or string.

The output is the encrypted data to be stored in the PDF file.